# Access external lib from oracle stored procedures

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

How do we refer to external libraries in oracle stored procedure?

I did this.

```
loadjava -jarasresource -user apps/xxx@instance sqljdbc.jar
```

(I am loading the lib required for jdbc connection to sql server 2000,)

now, in my oracle stored procedure I want to refer to this lib something like this.

```
create or replace and resolve java source named SQLConnect as 

    import java.sql.*;
    //import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;

   public class SQLConnect {

   public static String Test() {

    // Create a variable for the connection string.
    //JDBC:SQLSERVER://LOCALHOST:1433;" +"DATABASENAME=ADVENTUREWORKS;INTEGRATEDSECURITY=true;.
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://222.222.222.22:1433;databaseName=SQLSERVERNAME";
```

Please tell me how this can be done, as right now I am unable to access the library from my stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is, first load the java class or jar into the database.  You don't need the source if you already have loaded the jar.  Then write a Java Stored Procedure to wrap the java method of interest.  [Find out more.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/java.101/b12021/pub.htm#1006567)

However, looking at the specific library you want to work with - `SQLServerDriver` - I think you're still going to be disappointed.  That's not the right way to correct to SQL Server from Oracle. You need to check out [Heterogeneous Connectivity](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10764/toc.htm).